# Why do e.clientX and e.clientY function not gives output very smoothly on mouseOver?

Tags: javascript

Today I found some annoying thing with Javascript..
see with given below example -

HTML and  JAVASCRIPT :

```
<p>Click anywhere  | | | |.</p>

<script>
document.addEventListener('mouseover' ,function(e){
        console.log(`Position: (${e.clientX}, ${e.clientY})`);
    },false);
<script>
```

When I run above code in my browser (google-chrome) then it is not giving the output instatly.

When I move mouse from one position to other position then it must instantly give the output on console but it is not giving output smoothly.
What's the problem ?

Please try the `small` code in your browser to get what am i saying .

Answer (score 3):

mouseover is fired when the cursor transitions onto the bound element or any of its descendants.  In your case, it will fire when transitioning onto any element at all as you are binding to the document.  If I understand your question correctly, the event you want to listen to is mousemove.

Comment: _Thanks..! I achieved my answer with mousemove, but still i didn't clear why  mouseover isn't working ?_

Comment: Again, mouseover only fires when transitioning onto one element from another.  Paste your javascript into the chrome debugger console while stackoverflow is open and slowly move the mouse around the screen, paying close attention to when the even fires.  It'll happen every time you move onto a different element on the page.

Comment: _I cleared my confusion with the help of debugger and your suggestion .Thanks again_

Comment: a "thanks" is nice, but accepting my answer as correct is nicer... :-)

Comment: Really, @AbhishekKamal ?  Be considerate to the people who help you and *mark answers as correct* if they help!  We take the time to help you out, the least you can do is click a button.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  console.log(`Position: (${e.clientX}, ${e.clientY})`);
}, false);
```

```html
<p>Click anywhere | | | |.</p>
```

Try with ' mousemove '

Comment: _Thanks for give solution... but please tell me why mouseover isn't working ? and if you don't know the answer then discuss with your seniors and after tell me again_

Comment: ' mouseover ' can work if we move mouse to different element. Try to move your mouse in element p, it is not work. But will work when you move your mouse outside of element or different element

Comment: _Yes it is not working when i hover on any element, it only works at white screen . Works on white screen but not instantly ._